# What is the order of executing super() constructor and subclass methods in javascript object oriented programming?

Tags: javascript, class, object, constructor, this

Why is `this` undefined in `render()` method inside of the subclass?
Why `this` inside of the base class constructor refers to the created object based on subclass? I want to know the execution order in here.

```js
class baseClass {
    constructor() {
        this.render(); // why does "this" (not this.render()) refer to the created object based on derivedClass?
    }

    render() {
        console.log("won't get executed.");
    }
}

class derivedClass extends baseClass {
    foo = "foo"
    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log(this); 
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.foo); // why is "this" undefined?
        alert("rendered");
    }
}

new derivedClass;
```

Comment: It's `this.item` which is `undefined`, not `this`. Otherwise you'd get an error that `item` does not exist on `undefined`. Nowhere in this code is `item` added, that is why it doesn't exist when you try to read it.

Comment: of course. I made a silly mistake in my code snippet, sorry about that, I edited my post just now.

Comment: Initialization of the newly created instance starts from the parent class. When the parent class constructor is called from as a result of `super()` call from the child class constructor, `this` inside the parent class' constructor refers to the newly created instance to allow parent class to initialize the newly created instance before the child class.

Comment: Try and set this.foo = “foo” in the constructor.

Comment: @Yousaf What do you mean by "to allow parent class to initialize the newly created instance before the child class" ? initialize how? what initialization (initialize what)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To better understand how it works you can change your code a bit:

```
class baseClass {
  bar = 'bar';

  constructor() {
    console.log(
      `In baseClass constructor this is ${JSON.stringify(this, null, 2)}`
    );
    this.render(); // why does "this" (not this.render()) refer to the created object based on derivedClass?
  }

  render() {
    console.group();
    console.log(this);
    console.log('baseClass rendered');
    console.groupEnd();
  }
}

class derivedClass extends baseClass {
  foo = 'foo';
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log(
      `In derivedClass constructor this is ${JSON.stringify(this, null, 2)}`
    );
    this.render();
  }

  render() {
    console.group();
    console.log(this);
    console.log('derivedClass rendered');
    console.groupEnd();
  }
}

new derivedClass();
```

It will output:

```
In baseClass constructor this is {
  "bar": "bar"
}
  derivedClass { bar: 'bar' }
  derivedClass rendered
In derivedClass constructor this is {
  "bar": "bar",
  "foo": "foo"
}
  derivedClass { bar: 'bar', foo: 'foo' }
  derivedClass rendered
```

So the sequence is as follows:

1. `derivedClass` constructor is called when you do `new derivedClass();`
2. It calls the `baseClass` constructor
3. The data members are populated with what `baseClass` "owns"
4. The methods though are of `derivedClass`, that's why you see   "derivedClass rendered" when render is called from the `baseClass` constructor.
5. The data members of `derivedClass` are added
6. `derivedClass` constructor calls `render` again.

It is somewhat counter-intuitive, especially if you come from OOP background with C++, Java, etc. And I think this is the reason why some try to avoid classes and `this` in JavaScript entirely.